# Brass: Are shipyards "industries"?

Tags: brass

At the end of the canal phase all 'level 1 industry' tiles are removed.  Does this include level 1 shipyards?

If so - then why does the level 1 shipyard tile **not** have a canal marker on it, like all the other canal-phase-only tiles?

(EDIT for future clarity: The canal symbol is missing on **first edition** copies of the game. Thanks to Xi Huan for this info.)

I know that level 0 shipyards need to be developed before any can be built, and that level-2 shipyards can only be built during the railway phase.  Level-1 shipyards seem to fall into an ambiguous hole.  Only one can ever actually be built, the Liverpool one, because of the coal connectivity requirements.  This half suggests it could stay there when the railway phase is started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a mistake that the canal symbol is missing. If you look at the [second edition rule book](http://www.hexagonia.com/rules/Brass2ed.pdf), you see the canal symbol on a level 1 shipyard:

[image]

The rules also say

> If you have just completed the Canal Period then remove all canal 
>   and Tech level 1 Industry counters, along with any cubes on them, 
>   from the map.

No mention of the canal/rail road symbols. They a just reminders.

Since level 1 shipyards are also tech level 1 industries (they look and behave like the other industries and the shipyard counters are listed in the rules as industries counters), they are removed as well when the canal period is completed.

So the short answer is: **yes**.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks.  My copy is first edition and we were wondering whether to draw a canal symbol on the tile. It was clear Level 1 industries needed to be removed, but not clear that shipyards were industries within the definition of the game.